# How to put react on full screen when opening the project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fullscreen, react-typescript

I would like to know if I can open my React project with TypeScript in full screen without having to press F11.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following

```
componentDidMount() {
   appmainElmWrapperRef.requestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your example, sorry.

Comment: elm.requestFullscreen(); is JS function to enable fullscreen. So in react you need to do it with reference of the parent element. But you can also use document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].requestFullscreen();  Property, that is not a good practice in react.

Comment: I understand, but I'm using a functional component, and I don't know how to create this ref as you demonstrated. Do you have an example of a complete code to show me, please? It can be on github or anywhere else.